# How can i get rid of ' 403 Access Denied' error for SoundManager2 mp3 files, that are in the Downloads folder?

Tags: users, media

i have installed SoundManager2 to playback audio files but realized that anonymous users get a 403 Forbidden error when trying to play. These files are actually products. i attached to product type using 'File Attach' method. After that it moves the file to the downloads folder but cleverly when looking at the markup it says the file is in 'system/files'. unless i'm wrong there is no such dir.  For now,  i have the downloads permissions set to 'rwxrwxr-x'. I've also checked the Permissions page and set anything related to products and mp3's accessible to anonymous users.

any ideas?!, thanks!

Comment: This definitely sounds like a Permissions issue- double check those.

Comment: thanks i will. is that normal though, for the markup to read 'system/files' yet they reside in downloads? is there another folder perhaps, an alias or something that might be causing the problem?

Comment: Uploaded files should be in /sites - check /admin/config/media/file-system to make sure your paths are correct (i.e. sites/default/files)